# Changing GIF image src in Google Chrome makes the image stutter

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, gif

I'm writing jQuery code to change an `img` src attribute at different times using `setTimeout`.

I'm writing the correct code, but in Google Chrome it has a weird display issue, look at this slowed down recording as demonstration:

[image: slowed down recording of the page]

As you can see, the first gif resets and plays for a short time before changing to the second gif, an issue that can be reproduced with the following code:

```js
    $("#TestImg").attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif");

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#TestImg").attr("src", "https://media4.giphy.com/avatars/Kool-Aid/vBEBR9AYEYqq.gif");
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#TestImg").attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif");
    }, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="TestImg" />
```

It's displaying correctly in Microsoft Edge browser this is only happening in Google Chrome, things I have tried:

- Preloading the images
- hide/show or add/remove the `img` when changing the `src`

I'm looking to avoid this issue in Chrome by using workarounds if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try hard reload google chrome page ?
while using scripts in front end some time hard reload is necessary. 
Thanks.